# Custom button on infowindws (like modal Bootstrap button)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, infowindow

I Have an application wher inside a info window, appear a button "More Info" that open a modal view. The code is:

```
(function(marker, data) {// Attaching a click event to the current marker
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.position}, function(results, status) {
           if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0]) { //defino la direccion
                 address = results[0].formatted_address;
                 info = '<h4>' + marker.title + '</h4><h4>'+ address+'</h4>';
                 var content = document.createElement('div'),button;
                 content.innerHTML = info + '<br/>';
                 button = content.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
                 button.type = 'button';
                 button.value = 'More info';
                     google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function () {
                        offsetCenter(marker,data);
                      })
                  infoWindow.setContent(content);
```

My questions is about the style of the button. How can I add the button  with a style like the modal bootstrap buttons (ie btn-primary class button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the simple solution using   setAttribute property.
just using:

```
 button.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-info');
```

I get the bootsrap button on infowindows. You can chang btn-info for another class.

Hope it helps.